# Azure blob storage trying to upload the same file to different folders

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blob

I am trying to upload multiple files with the name 'data' to the Azure blob, I am uploading them in different folders in my function, I create a new one for each new 'data' file, but still I get the error `BlobAlreadyExists`The specified blob already exists.Any ideas ?

`

```
 blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
 blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name+'\\'+id+'\\'+uploadnr, blob=filename)
 with open(pathF+filename,"rb") as data:
      blob_client.upload_blob(data)
      print(f"Uploaded {filename}.")
```

`

Comment: I think you should define the folder as part of the filename for the upload. Container name should be only the container. Folders don't really exist in blob storage, they are just part of the name, for example "folder/another/file.txt" is the name but in portal it is visualized as being inside two folders.

Comment: So then it should be blob=id+'\\'+uploadnr+'\\'+filename ?

Comment: `So then it should be blob=id+'\\'+uploadnr+'\\'+filename ?` - that's correct. Though I would use `/` as delimiter instead of `\\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> `BlobAlreadyExists`The specified blob already exists.

***Initially I tried in my environment and got same results:***

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

connection_string="<Connect_string>"
container="test\data"
filename="sample1.pdf"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container,filename)
with  open("path+filename","rb") as  data:
blob_client.upload_blob(data)
print(f"Uploaded {filename}.")
```

**Console:**

[image]

After I made changes in code it executed successfully.

[image]